# List of String implicit conversions like +=

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Consider the following snippet. += is not a member of java.lang.String, so I guess there is some sort of Implicit conversion going on. How do I find a list of such predefined implicit conversions acting on String?

```
scala> var x = "asdf"
x: java.lang.String = asdf

scala> x += x

scala> x
res2: java.lang.String = asdfasdf
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You picked a particularly bad example. `+=` is, in a sense, part of `String`. See this comment on the Javadoc for `java.lang.String`:

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( `+` ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings.

You'll have to look up [Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) to find more information about it (15.18.1). But, then again, Scala is not Java, so `+` is also part of the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (12.3.1).

So far I have spoken of `+`, not `+=`. However, Scala has a special syntactic sugar for assignment. As described in section 6.12.4, except for `<=`, `>=`, `!=` and operators starting with an `=`, any operator symbol (see "operator characters" in chapter 1) that ends in an equal sign will be reinterpreted if it does not exist as a method. Specifically,

```
x += 1
```

will be reinterpreted as

```
x = x + 1
```

That will happen regardless of whether `x` is a `var`, so one might occasionally see an error message "`reassignment to val`".

So, as you can see, `+=` is really part of `String`, through an exception in Java specification that was replicated in Scala specification, plus a bit of syntactic sugar.

Which doesn't mean there aren't methods not in `java.lang.String` that can be used with it through implicit conversions. I'll leave that to the other answers, however. If I were you, I'd change the method in the question, to make it correct. Besides, `+=` is unsearchable in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

You need to look in [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef%24.html) -  all implicits that are defined there would be always in scope (so you don't need to import them).

If you look in [it's source code](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//library/scala/Predef.scala#L309), you will  find this section:

```
// Strings and CharSequences ------------

...

implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps = new StringOps(x)
implicit def unaugmentString(x: StringOps): String = x.repr

...
```

Answer (score 4):

[StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html) defines implicit conversions for `String`. It gets imported into the scope in `scala.Predef` along with other useful things.

Answer (score 4):

Not specific to `String`, but the Scala REPL has a neat feature to see *all* the implicits in scope:

```
scala> :implicits
No implicits have been imported other than those in Predef.

scala> :implicits -v
/* 96 implicit members imported from scala.Predef */
  /* 66 inherited from scala.Predef */
  implicit def Double2double(x: jl.Double): Double
  implicit def byte2double(x: Byte): Double
  implicit def char2double(x: Char): Double
  ...

  /* 30 inherited from scala.LowPriorityImplicits */
  implicit def genericWrapArray[T](xs: Array[T]): mutable.WrappedArray[T]
  implicit def wrapBooleanArray(xs: Array[Boolean]): mutable.WrappedArray[Boolean]
  implicit def wrapByteArray(xs: Array[Byte]): mutable.WrappedArray[Byte]
  ...
```

---

It's also worth noting that implicits don't have to be in scope to be applied. For example, we can define an implicit conversion in a companion object,

```
case class Foo(s: String)
object Foo { implicit def string2Foo(s: String) = Foo(s.reverse) }
```

and then apply it, even though its not in scope,

```
scala> val f: Foo = "hello"
f: Foo = Foo(olleh)
```

The `Foo` companion object is searched for implicits because the target type is `Foo`. For more info, see Daniel Sobral's answer to: [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)